# Retrieve data from bridge table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

[image: DB]

I'm having an issue to retrieve "**portion**" data from table "ingredient_recipe". Is there any way to get the "**portion**" data without using Query Builder? This is my code for retrieve ingredient in recipe model. The problem is I want to retrieve portion value from Recipe model.

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
  public function ingredients(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the pivot table column in your relationship

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient')->withPivot('portion');
}
```

Then access it like

```
$recipe = Recipe::find(1);

foreach ($recipe->ingredients as $ingredient) {
    echo $ingredient->pivot->portion;
}
```